# Upload existing java WAR file to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a working maven java web project on an EC2 instance running a Jetty server (I dropped the .WAR file for that project in the jetty webapps/ folder). However, when I try to upload this same .WAR file to an Elastic Beanstalk environment through the AWS console it doesn't work at all. What changes do I need to make to my web project to get it to work on Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: as far as I know EB support only tomcat. if you have some jetty specific code and you must to use jetty you can try this tutorial : https://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/elastic-beanstalk.html

Comment: Well the latest Java SE platforms on Elastic Beanstalk support Jetty. See here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html and 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy a WAR as application version in Elastic Beanstalk you need to use the [Java Tomcat platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html).

You other option with java in Elastic Beanstalk is the [Java SE platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html). But you need to upload a zip file as an application version in this case, not a WAR. So your better chance of working with jetty and Java SE ELB platform is to embed jetty within you application and build a fat runnable jar.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I uploaded the same .war I was using in my jetty /webapps folder to an elastic beanstalk environment running tomcat and it works perfectly. Thank you, sir.